# How to remove Grand total for each bar from only Grand Summary series in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I wanted to remove the **Grand Total For Each Bars** bar from Grand Summary series. I have tried to remove it but it removes from all series April,May,Jun. I need to keep in other series group but not in Grand Summary. Here is my data and script. You can check if categories has Grand Summary then the **Grand Total For Each Bars** bar would not show in series.
Here is my script:

```js
var seriesData = [
    {
        "data": [
            690,
            230,
            230,
            230
        ],
        "name": "Grand Total For Each Bars"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            230,
            100,
            100,
            100
        ],
        "name": "April"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            230,
            50,
            50,
            50
        ],
        "name": "May"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            230,
            80,
            80,
            80
        ],
        "name": "Jun"
    }
];

var categoriesData = ['Grand Summary', 'April', 'May', 'Jun'];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Remove Grand total for each bars in Grand total sumary series group',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categoriesData,
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
       
    },
    yAxis: {
       
        title: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    
    series: seriesData
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
      
    </p>
</figure>
```

[image]
Thanks

Comment: You could just remove the first value of the first object?

Comment: If i remove it removes from all series group. It should not remove from all series group

Comment: aahh i understand. please see my answer

Comment: Yes i check it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not 'remove' it, but set it to `null`.

A hardcoded solution:

```
seriesData[0].data[0] = null;
```

Use `find()` if you need something dynamic.

```js
var seriesData = [
    {
        "data": [
            690,
            230,
            230,
            230
        ],
        "name": "Grand Total For Each Bars"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            230,
            100,
            100,
            100
        ],
        "name": "April"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            230,
            50,
            50,
            50
        ],
        "name": "May"
    },
    {
        "data": [
            230,
            80,
            80,
            80
        ],
        "name": "Jun"
    }
];

seriesData[0].data[0] = null;

var categoriesData = ['Grand Summary', 'April', 'May', 'Jun'];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Remove Grand total for each bars in Grand total sumary series group',
        align: 'left'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categoriesData,
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
            text: null
        },
       
    },
    yAxis: {
       
        title: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high'
        },
        labels: {
            overflow: 'justify'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0
    },
    
    series: seriesData
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 310px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#container {
    height: 400px;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
      
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: Thanks it's working. There is one thing in it. Can we add new bar on left side and show sum of all categories except Grand Summary. If Grand Total Of All Bars. please check the image
https://pasteboard.co/RF6cS6Q4wB9l.png

Comment: Mm i'm not quite sure how to do that quickly. I might look in to that later today. But I'd suggest asking that in a separate question.

Comment: Ok sure hope you understand my question.